# Animating ListView item to trash

Tags: android, listview, animation

Below my ListView, I have a bar with a trash can on it.

When some action is performed, suppose it is simply clicking on the item, I would like the item to animate down to the trash can.  This means both moving downward and shrinking horizontally to a width of 0.

How can this be achieved?  I suspect it involves creating a bitmap of the item and then animating that bitmap downward and ever smaller.  This also means, depending on where the list item is relative to the screen, it may need to shrink faster than other times (ie: if the list item is already close to the bottom of the screen instead of the top).  I'm just not sure how to achieve any of this.

The only animation I've done involves presenting a bar from the bottom of the screen.  I've no experience with moving around a free-floating object and altering its size.

Could someone provide me with some good direction?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to achieve that target:

First, you need to create a "hoovered" copy of your list item. To do that, you need to inflate a new view, which has the same structure as the list items in your listview. After that, you need to add that to the windows manager, like this:

```
            WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            windowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
            windowParams.x = item.getLeft();
            windowParams.y = item.getTop();
            windowParams.height = item.getHeight();
            windowParams.width = item.getWidth();
            windowParams.flags =
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
            windowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
            windowParams.windowAnimations = 0;

            View hooveredView = getClonedView(item);

            // Add the hoovered view to the window manager, as a new view in the screen
            WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mWindowManager.addView(hooveredView, windowParams);
```

Now, create new Animation class which gets the WindowParams, and change the x and y coordinates, in order to move the hoovered item to the lower trash bar. Update the new view position by using this code:

```
        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mViewToAnimate, mWindowParams);
```

You can also play with the width and height in order to simulate shrinking of the view.

In order to animate the empty spot left on the list, you can use my ExpandAnimation explained on my blog:
http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/

That's pretty much it. If you need more details - just ask.

Comment: Where's the getClonedView method? Eclipse can't seem to find it.

Comment: As I wrote: "First, you need to create a "hoovered" copy of your list item..". That method suppose to return a copy of the view you wish to animate, the implementation for that is on you.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks for your reply. I already solved this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as performing the animation, take a look at [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html). It looks like you will want to build an `AnimationSet` comprised of a `ScaleAnimation`, `AlphaAnimation`, and `TranslateAnimation`. Then you apply that animation to whatever you create to move around over the list view. Off the top of my head, I would probably approach that aspect by creating a copy of the item that will be deleted, animating it to the 'trash' then deleting the original item. But that approach may be harder/less efficient than creating a Bitmap.